# 'TSearchInput' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'RotatingItemSearchInput'

Tags: typescript

I am facing an issue where I want to let every record in object have different value types but getting these errors:

1 - 'TSearchInput' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'RotatingItemSearchInput'

2 - 'K' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'number'

I have created this simplistic demo:

```
class RotatingItemSearchInput {}
class OtherItemSearchInput {}

const rotatingItemService = (input: RotatingItemSearchInput) =>
  new Promise((res: (val: number) => void) => res(1));

const otherItemService = (input: OtherItemSearchInput) =>
  new Promise((res: (val: string) => void) => res('result'));

const filtersMap: Record<
  string,
  <TSearchInput, K>() => {
    searchInput: TSearchInput;
    search: (searchInput: TSearchInput) => Promise<K>;
  }
> = {
  rotatingItem: () => ({
    searchInput: new RotatingItemSearchInput(),
    search: (searchInput) => rotatingItemService(searchInput),
  }),
  otherItem: () => ({
    searchInput: new OtherItemSearchInput(),
    search: (searchInput) => otherItemService(searchInput),
  }),
};
```

I would appreciate it if you could please help me fix this.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBKD2AXMiCWA7A5gSUQUwFsBlPMAJ2AAtt0AHAV0WgG8BfAKFEhgHlFK8ZXIRLkqNBkzbtO8dBCZkkKDDnzFBAN1TA80ALzQAFBkkAuOMrRZhGsdTqMAlAYB87aNHR4A7tAAKSgSoEHhGRmR4EBZGmmAgFuj0BABGgi76rtCa8KgAJhlZkRBGAIxOTgDcMsByCtBIAkLqJGTaugbGpowWfE22ohQOkoUeXr4BQSFhEVExcQnQCmSqhdm5BW7QxUYA5MX0IIi7FdWy8kwAZqhHghAAsmC0FrB4tWR5ADxjy6oANGNPgAVQbiRyIP7QADSriMa2YY08oXsEh60BBpCGqMQ1U8SMxVBiyKx4IsGJR4LWgXgwVCnxhuOgHCyhgRniUyGsakIMTWRjZeOJYPM4z8CE5qgGBOGjDhALxS2lROl2LWHJUNhaWh0YSFMsQTnlTMNY0aglsvK2-MRiopIu8fj65q1dtlJoVeuVroNWzNzRE2t0Rj1qqNrBNrGqQA)

Comment: It might be helpful to add an example of how you intend to use this code. In `rotatingItemService` and `otherItemService`, the `input` argument is not used for anything. In the object returned by the methods in `filtersMap`, the `searchInput` property doesn't seem to have any correlation to the `search` method.

Comment: These are just a dummy services I mentioned here for simplicity. Eventually, in each search callback I will be calling the different services to get search results from the database. Just a little context, I have a graphql search api which takes bunch of filters as input. Say there is a `User` object and it has the schema looks like: `user{ locations{ id } resources{ id } ... } ` This filter maps contains all the data required i.e. search filter/input value for each relation and their assoicated search service to make a Users search.

Answer (score 0):

See this

```
interface Obj<T, K> {
  [key: string]: {
    searchInput: T;
    search: (val: T) => Promise<K>;
  };
}
```